# Как в pytest прервать тест по истечении конкретного времени?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Тесты не для вэба, т.е. без селениума.

Есть тест с одним и тем же порядком действий но с разными входными данными(с помощью "@pytest.mark.parametrize()"), генерируется строка кидается в тест и так далее, столько раз сколько укажу.

Так вот, иногда одна такая итерация занимает слишком много времени, есть ли способ прервать тест по времени, например если тест выполняется больше 10 секунд считать его зафэйленым?
Набросал пример:

```
import pytest
from random import randint
from time import sleep


@pytest.mark.parametrize('wait', [randint(1, 12) for _ in range(10)])
def test_ttt(wait):
    sleep(wait)
    '''Не сравнивая wait как число, 
    если способ тестам которые выполняются 
    более, допустим, 10 секунд присваивать статус "failed"?'''
```

Comment: Можно использовать плагин [pytest-timeout](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/)

Comment: @insolor Штука прикольная, но в конкретно в моём примере не поможет, при срабатывании тайм аута стопятся все тесты, а надо что бы только тот на котором произошло лишнее ожидание. Наверно с \@pytest.mark.parametrize в связке лучше не использовать

Comment: У меня падают только тесты не прошедшие по таймауту, выполнение тестов не прекращается после фейла: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTcz.png

Comment: @insolor Не понимаю что я делаю не так(. Вроде же одно и тоже, может у вас pytest как то настроен по особенному, какая нибудь инишка или conftest.py? https://clip2net.com/clip/m562181/8807a-clip-137kb.png?nocache=1

Comment: У меня linux, возможно из-за этого)

Comment: Попробуйте еще выбрать способ таймаута `@pytest.mark.timeout(method='thread')` или `@pytest.mark.timeout(method='signal')`